# Host MEAN STACK APP using Github gh-pages

Tags: github-pages

https://github.com/shaneyvincent/MEAN-STACK-message-app <-- the github
https://shaneyvincent.github.io/MEAN-STACK-message-app/ <--what the host shows

Hello I am trying to Host a mean stack app using gh-pages.

When I run the site locally I use node server.js ( listening on port  5000
 connected to mongo) and then I use gulp serve to launch the page. it shows serving files from my SRC folder.

When I push to gh pages branch, and launch the page I get a 404 error, Why can it not find my index file in my SRC folder, also I tried copying the index.html  and placing it in the main folder, but then after I push that it just reads a blank page. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your [index.js](https://github.com/shaneyvincent/MEAN-STACK-message-app/blob/master/index.js) is the first problem.

Line #4 (`app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));`) will not work on Github Pages. It only allows for client-side languages or Jekyll, not server-side NodeJS apps.